# Cart button in android application.

Tags: android

This is a general question. I could not get any answer for this on the Google, so asking on the stackoverflow.

Some of the android apps have cart button at the top of the activity(action bar).
For example I have attached an image of amazon android application.
All the products would be listed through `webview` and when the user places order on amazon an order cart updates with the number from 0 to 1 which is in action bar.
This updation is happening in android from `webview` to some widget used in android most probably.

Could anyone let us know how this could be achieved or totally the whole activity itself is `webview`? I want to know what widget are they using and how are they updating the cart in the activity.

Any pointers to examples would be really helpful.

Attached is the image of amazon android application screen.

[image: Image of the amazon android application]

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the standard action bar items can be updated on runtime.

However, the action bar supports the ability to add a **custom layout** to it. In this case I don't see any difficulties in setting a listener when an item is added to the cart, and reflect this on UI by updating that custom layout.

**UPDATED:**
To add a custom layout, from the code:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```

or from the styles:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
  .....
  <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

Now, in your `R.layout.custom_action_bar` you'll have that button with a number above representing the number of items in the cart. Obviously that number should be a `TextView`, that will be incremented every time an item is added to the cart.

For this you will need a listener in your activity, that will update that TextView, for example:

```
@Override
public void onItemAdded(){
   cart.setText(CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_CART);
}
```

Comment: if you could give an example, that is what I am looking at it. thanks.

Comment: thanks but how do you get that value of click of a href rendering in `webview` shopping list items to android, example attached `<a onclick="addToCart(parameter1,parameter2);" href="javascript:void(0);">Add to Cart</a>`.

Comment: Sorry, I completly omitted the WebView here in this example. I thought the app will be native.

Comment: can we make the whole shopping cart as native application, I did try at that but could not get any examples or pointers explaining. do you have any pointers on building shopping cart in android native application. thanks.

Comment: You could go with native app version of course, but in this case the server side should provide you with an API, so you'll be able to make requests and get the list of products.

Comment: you mean to say pass an arguments what we want to search to the url and get back the details in json format, construct an ListView and render it. but amazon app probably(as when you see the styling it looks like it is coming from their website) loads all the details from the `webview` and then whenever the user orders it gets reflected in the action bar. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

they use [action bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), action bar is window feather that display on top bar,
  for more info and example of this  you can see the source code for google I/O app  [here](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, this may not be a proper answer to the question.

I think you can do it using `WebViewClient` and `onPageFinished`. Watch for a specic pattern of URL. If the pattern matches you can perform the action u needed.

One more method, think about this too,

Let the app send request to the server to update the cart. The app will frequently send request to the server  to check for cart update.

:)

Answer (score 0):

inside your res/menu/menuitem.xml you can define the following option:

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/yourcustomlayout"
```

where yourcustomlayout could be

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:src="@drawable/cart" />

<TextView
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    style="@style/DefaultTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground" />
```

inside onCreateOptionsMenu you can take the references to your textview as follow:

```
private TextView cartTV;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.virtual_betting, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
    cartTV = (TextView) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.pallino);

    return true;
}
```

and update when you need to update

Comment: Sorry old comment, but I am looking to update my cart icon in real time. So If I add something to my cart. I should be able to see 1 or 2 near the cart icon. I figure your code can do the same but how do I update the numbers in actionbar? Can let me know that?

Comment: @TheDevMan yes it is very old and I don't recall it, btw I am keeping a instance of the TextView representing the cart as member variable for the Activity/Fragment. So I am pretty sure that you just need to call `cartTV.settText(String.valueOf(itemsInCart));` when the *insert-in-cart-event* occurs